# Can equation solving be done in parallel?

Tags: equation-solving, parallelization

I'm solving a set of equations that look like:

```
Solve[cx == (((((x3 - x2) * t + x2) - ((x2 - x1) * t + x1)) * t + ((x2 - x1) * t + x1)) - ((((x2 - x1) * t + x1) - ((x1 - x0) * t + x0)) * t + ((x1 - x0) * t + x0))) / Sqrt[(((((x3 - x2) * t + x2) - ((x2 - x1) * t + x1)) * t + ((x2 - x1) * t + x1)) - ((((x2 - x1) * t + x1) - ((x1 - x0) * t + x0)) * t + ((x1 - x0) * t + x0))) * (((((x3 - x2) * t + x2) - ((x2 - x1) * t + x1)) * t + ((x2 - x1) * t + x1)) - ((((x2 - x1) * t + x1) - ((x1 - x0) * t + x0)) * t + ((x1 - x0) * t + x0))) + (((((y3 - y2) * t + y2) - ((y2 - y1) * t + y1)) * t + ((y2 - y1) * t + y1)) - ((((y2 - y1) * t + y1) - ((y1 - y0) * t + y0)) * t + ((y1 - y0) * t + y0))) * (((((y3 - y2) * t + y2) - ((y2 - y1) * t + y1)) * t + ((y2 - y1) * t + y1)) - ((((y2 - y1) * t + y1) - ((y1 - y0) * t + y0)) * t + ((y1 - y0) * t + y0)))] && cy == (((((y3 - y2) * t + y2) - ((y2 - y1) * t + y1)) * t + ((y2 - y1) * t + y1)) - ((((y2 - y1) * t + y1) - ((y1 - y0) * t + y0)) * t + ((y1 - y0) * t + y0))) / Sqrt[(((((x3 - x2) * t + x2) - ((x2 - x1) * t + x1)) * t + ((x2 - x1) * t + x1)) - ((((x2 - x1) * t + x1) - ((x1 - x0) * t + x0)) * t + ((x1 - x0) * t + x0))) * (((((x3 - x2) * t + x2) - ((x2 - x1) * t + x1)) * t + ((x2 - x1) * t + x1)) - ((((x2 - x1) * t + x1) - ((x1 - x0) * t + x0)) * t + ((x1 - x0) * t + x0))) + (((((y3 - y2) * t + y2) - ((y2 - y1) * t + y1)) * t + ((y2 - y1) * t + y1)) - ((((y2 - y1) * t + y1) - ((y1 - y0) * t + y0)) * t + ((y1 - y0) * t + y0))) * (((((y3 - y2) * t + y2) - ((y2 - y1) * t + y1)) * t + ((y2 - y1) * t + y1)) - ((((y2 - y1) * t + y1) - ((y1 - y0) * t + y0)) * t + ((y1 - y0) * t + y0)))], t, Reals]
```

This has 11 symbols and solving it, or attempting to, would take a very long time. On my 8 core 5960X it only uses 13% of my CPU. Is there anything I can do to make it use all my cores to find, or attempt to find, a solution faster?

Comment: Where did this set of equations come from?

Comment: There is no method to have solving equations parallelized.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You cannot solve equations in parallel if they share variables to be solved for. Though you can speed up computation if the number of unknowns increase  in subsequent equations by solving a few at a time and substituting the unknown in subsequent equations before solving them. I wrote this program for maxima https://www.academia.edu/7726011/Progressively_solving_equations_from_customized_row_reduction_algorithm  , it reduced the time taken to solve by 3 times, my guess is that it will be equally relevant for MMA.

Comment: @J.M. I wrote it on paper. It's attempting to solve for the time t on cubic bezier curve defined by (x0, y0), (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3) that is equal to a given normalized tangent vector. There should be a maximum of two solutions in the range [0, 1]. I have a solution for this problem already, but it has floating point issues (part of the calculation results in very tiny decimals for some edge cases) when converted to a computer. Was trying to see if Mathematica would give another result. I can try to see if Mathematica can take the solution and simplify or rearrange it maybe.

Comment: In that case, do you really need a symbolic solution? If you plug in explicit values for the control points, things should be much more manageable.

Comment: @J.M. It's strange. Even without symbols Mathematica is unable to solve for t. http://pastebin.com/hfdqksbH It's just a quadratic equation. Also the answer is t = 0.5, but the program just runs forever.

Comment: Ignore that. The software glitched apparently and I had to close it all. It wouldn't process any statement.

Comment: It looks like your equations are linear. There exists a lot of work into parallel Gaussian elimination. I don't know if Mathematica can utilize it.